# Capture text selected on a web page (a la politico.com)

Tags: jquery, events, html

I'd like to be able to figure out the text that a user highlights on a given web page (we use jQuery if that helps), to capture and store in a database.

Politico.com does this in a pretty slick way -- if you highlight text on an article page there and copy it, you copy not just the highlighted text but also a link back to the politico.com article with an ID that is associated with the text you highlighted.  In [this example](http://www.politico.com/news/stories/1009/28099.html#ixzz0TNvdwh0h), I highlighted text in the third paragraph before copying and pasting, which inserted the id/hash/whatever "ixzz0TNvdwh0h".

Anybody know how this is done?

Comment: which browser is this in? if I do this in IE8 or FF it does nothing more than regular copy/paste.

Comment: I'm using safari right now...although I find it odd it would be safari/webkit-only, since it seems like a non-trivial amount of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet that will take the selection from the browser using a method called `window.getSelectedText` [Selected Text From Code Toad](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp)